# Lookup records in a data extension and match on mailing data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, lookup

I'm trying to write AMPscript that will take the data extension I'm mailing to and see if a record exists in a separate data ext. If it does then write to a value on one of our tables. Here's the AMPscript I'm currently using.

```
%%[
VAR @Subscriber_Key
SET @Subscriber_Key = _subscriberkey

SET @SOID = Lookup("Contact_Table", "SOID", "Subscriber_Key", @Subscriber_Key)

SET @Reactivate = Lookup("External_DataExt1", "SOID", "Subscriber_Key", @Subscriber_Key)

SET @PrimaryEmail = Lookup("External_DataExt2", "SOID", "Subscriber_Key", @Subscriber_Key)
]%%
<br>
<br>


%%[
IF @SOID == '%%=v(@Reactivate)=%%' then
SET @SubGoal_SL = 'Reactivate'


ELSEIF @SOID == '%%=v(@PrimaryEmail)=%%' then
SET @SubGoal_SL = 'Primary New User'

ELSE SET @SubGoal_SL = 'Successful Customer'

ENDIF
]%%
```

Comment: Hi Mike - can you please specify exactly the issue you have with your current code and what isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**v()**](https://ampscript.guide/v) function is only for use outside of AMPscript blocks.  No need to use it inside the `%%[` `]%%`:

```
%%[

VAR @Subscriber_Key
SET @Subscriber_Key = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")

var @SOID, @Reactivate, @PrimaryEmail
SET @SOID = Lookup("Contact_Table", "SOID", "Subscriber_Key", @Subscriber_Key)
SET @Reactivate = Lookup("External_DataExt1", "SOID", "Subscriber_Key", @Subscriber_Key)
SET @PrimaryEmail = Lookup("External_DataExt2", "SOID", "Subscriber_Key", @Subscriber_Key)

IF @SOID == @Reactivate then

    SET @SubGoal_SL = 'Reactivate'

ELSEIF @SOID == @PrimaryEmail then

    SET @SubGoal_SL = 'Primary New User'

ELSE 

    SET @SubGoal_SL = 'Successful Customer'

ENDIF

]%%
```

Comment: I will give this a try. Thanks!